# About "Restore Purchase " button in android and IOS

Tags: android, ios, testing, manual-testing

I won to ask what android games should have a restore button or not ??

I Searched on google and read all articles but I did not find a satisfactory answer.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

iOS and Android both have different ways to implement the "Restore-Purchases" functionality.

In iOS, if your app offers non-consumable purchases such as a "collection of exercise tutorials for a fitness app" then a "Restore-Purchase" button is mandatory. if it offers a consumable purchase such as a "Examples are in-game currency and extras" then it's not mandatory.

So it's always recommended to add a "Restore-Purchases" button. Yes, it might be a change in the label name in the Android app because there are no such Apple guideline restrictions to set specific names as compared with iOS.

Answer (score 0):

The decision to include a "Restore Purchase" button in an Android game depends on whether the game has in-app purchases or not. If the game offers in-app purchases that unlock content or features, then it is recommended to include a "Restore Purchase" button.

The purpose of the "Restore Purchase" button is to allow users to restore any in-app purchases they may have made on a previous device or after a reinstall of the app. Without a "Restore Purchase" button, users may have to repurchase the content or features they had previously bought.

So, if your Android game has in-app purchases, it's a good idea to include a "Restore Purchase" button to ensure a smooth experience for users who have already made purchases.

However, if your game does not have any in-app purchases, then a "Restore Purchase" button is not necessary.